# While Dynamically loading xap using MEF how to pass a parameter to the xap file?

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, mef

Hi I have created a simple Main application and two InjectedApplications (InjectedApplication1 and InjectedApplication2) using an aritcle [Simplified MEF: Dynamically Loading a Silverlight .xap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86016/Simplified-MEF-Dynamically-Loading-a-Silverlight-x).

What i want to do then is how do we pass a value from Main Application to Injected application?

Here is the scenario: I have Main Application in which i Inject xap on demand. Untill here everything works fine as mentioned in the above article. I need to extend few things from there:

The xap (injected one) should have the code to load values for some particuilar ID. so when i load this xap in the Main application(Where the injected xap is loaded) i want to pass a value(some ID) to injected XAP so that the xap will load information for that particuilar ID.

How can we achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have [`Export`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.exportattribute.aspx) attributes on the types on the injected application.  In those attribute, you can define an interface.  Have the exported type implement that same interface.  When you construct objects using MEF, you will have access to the exported interface.  You can use that to pass data to the constructed object.

I recommend defining the interfaces in a separate shared library project.

If you can't or don't want to do that, you could use an Event Aggrigator like as [MVVM Light's](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) Messenger.  The Messenger has a static `Default` property.  I'm pretty sure the two xap files will share the same Default Messenger.  You can then send and receive data that way.

**Example**

Shared Lib

```
public interface IFoo
{
    object Data { get; set; }
}
```

Injected App

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

Main App

```
public class Bar
{
    [Import]
    public IFoo MyFoo { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you call `CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this)` on `Bar`, `MyFoo` will be set to an instance of `Foo` from Injected App.  Because this implements `IFoo,` you are able to use this interface to interact with the class `Foo`.

If you need any more clarification, I'll need to see your code.

Comment: Actually I am new to MEF and i understood a little from what you have said. Can you be little more descriptive? Appreciate your response.

Comment: @user841612 - Learning MEF while trying to do complicated things is difficult.  I would recommend reading up on MEF: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF I wrote this article for just this reason.  Unfortunately, I'm not skilled enough in XAP files to help you out on that side of things but it looks like cadrell0 might be on the right track.  Good luck.